# Delay timer circuit

Tags: mosfet, timer, delay

I want to design a timer circuit to turn on a MOSFET based switch for 15 seconds. I did research on the internet but couldn't find any help.
The idea is that if we give a voltage pulse on the gate of the transistor, it turns on the switch for 15 seconds and then turns off. I know it's there needs to be some circuitry other than just a MOSFET, but I can't figure it out. So it would be great if someone points me in the right direction. Thanks.

Comment: You want a one-shot timer.  This can be made with a 555.

Comment: Where is this 'voltage pulse' coming from?  What is the magnitude and duration of said pulse?

Comment: Coming from a switch and it should be a couple of hundred ms as it is from a physical switch.

Comment: CD4060 digital timers are cheap and the clock can easily be divided down to minutes or hours without the need for super low leakage caps. Any output can be gated with the clock input to stop the counter and the switch can reset the counter.  The active high can be inverted with a transistor to switch something On. Decoupling cap and possible input switch cap are needed to reduce stray noise.

Comment: It's known as a 'monoshot'.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned, a 555 timer in one-shot/monostable mode is probably the easiest as you can buy them at RadioShack and there are guides all over for hooking them up. Can you share the MOSFET characteristics and those for the rest of the circuit?  You’ll need to make sure that the 555 is applying adequate voltage to the gate of the MOSFET.

Comment: The mosfet must be able to handle at least 12V and 1A between drain and source.